# Assets\BlinkScript.cs(9,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Text' could not be found

Tags: c#

everytime i try to start my game it gives me a  error

Assets\BlinkScript.cs(9,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Text' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and ive tried everything and now i dont know what to do here is my code somebody please help me

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BlinkScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Uses;
    public float cooldown, distance, speed, destinationMultiplier, cameraHeight;
    public Text UIText;
    public Transform Cam;
    public LayerMask layerMask;

    int maxUses;
    float cooldownTimer;
    bool blinking = false;
    Vector3 destination;
    ParticleSystem trail;


    void Start()
    {
        trail = transform.Find("trail").GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        maxUses = Uses;
        cooldownTimer = cooldown;
        UItext.text = Uses.ToString();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(keyCode.Q))
        {
            Blink();
        }

        if (Uses < maxUses)
        {
            if (cooldownTimer > 0) cooldownTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            else { Uses += 1; cooldownTimer = cooldown; UItext.text = Uses.ToString(); }
        }

        if (Blinking)
        {
            var dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, destination);
            if(dist > 0.5f)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destination, Time.DeltaTime * speed);
            }
            else { blinking = false; }
        }
    }

    void Blink()
    {
        if(Uses > 0)
        {
            Uses -= 1;
            UItext.text = Uses.ToString();
            trail.play();

            RaycastHit hit;
            if(physics.Raycast(Cam.position, Cam.forward, out hit, distance, layerMask))
            {
                destination = hit.point * destinationMultiplier;
                Debug.DrawLine(Cam.position, hit.point * destinationMultiplier, Color.yellow, 2);
            }
            else
            {
                destination = (Cam.position * Cam.forward.normalized * distance) * destinationMultiplier;
                Debug.DrawRay(Cam.position, (Cam.forward * distance) * destinationMultiplier, Color.green, 2);
            }

            destination.y += cameraHeight;
            blinking = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `using UnityEngine.UI;` at the top of your code.

Comment: if i do that it give me 10 more errors so i cant do that